# Create rxjava observation

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

How can I create an observation like in the picture?
[Click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hwq.png)
I want to get the click event 1, 3 and 4 and get rid of 2 because 1, 2, 3 is very close (< 200ms between each other).
If i have the click event 1,2,3,4,5,6................7,8,9..........10, I want to get only 1,6,7,9,10. Because 1,2,3,4,5,6 happen very close to each other (let say < 200ms), i only want to get the first and the last of them.
Sorry for my bad English and it's quite hard to explain :)

Comment: Have you tried to use `sampleFirst()` operator to gather only the ones you want? Did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator is what you need.

For example:

```
    Observable.from(events).buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
       subscribe(objects -> System.out.println(String.format("got {} items", objects.size())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Debounce operator to skip certain events based on time. This is the documentation of Debounce operator.

> In this operator, a time window starts every time a value is received. Once the window expires, the value is emitted. If, however, another value is received before the window expires, the previous value is rejected and the window restarts for the next value.

So let's look at the simple example below.

```
    Observable.range(0, 10)
            .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In here integer values 0 - 10 are emitted. Let's say 1 emits 20 milliseconds after 0 and 2 emits 120 milliseconds after 1.

So the debounce operator will emit only 1 and 2 since 0 and 1 occurred within the time frame. While 1 and 2 were spaced apart by 100 milliseconds.

[image]

[Documentation](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/5.%20Time-shifted%20sequences.md#debouncing)